# Pick up multiple variables with get_context_data Django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a question about CBV Django process and `get_context_data()`.

I would like to get some different variables and I don't overcome to do it with my function.

This is the function :

```
class IdentitySocietePDFCreatingView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView) :

    template_name = 'Identity_Societe_PDF.html'
    model = Societe

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) :

        SID = Logger.login(lib.Global_variables.GED_LOG_USER, lib.Global_variables.GED_LOG_MDP)

        context_data = super(IdentitySocietePDFCreatingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        id = self.kwargs['id']
        societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id)

        obj = Societe.objects.filter (Nom=societe.Nom, SIRET=societe.SIRET, SIREN=societe.SIREN, Ville=societe.Ville)

        if obj:
            sc_obj = obj[0]

            ''' Rest of my script ''''
            ''' I have a variable named folderID which must be in my template ''''

        context_data['queryset'] = obj

        return context_data
```

My question is :

How I can add `folderID` variable inside `context_data` ? I have to display in my template `obj` and `folderID` but I don't overcome to add both variable in context_data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context_data` is a dict, you can add as many things to it as you like.

```
context_data['folderID'] = 'foo'
context_data['obj'] = 'bar'
```

Comment: Ok I was naive with my question ... Thank you ! @DanielRoseman All the time I used `context` based on Functions Based View and context_data works the same with Class Based View ..